# Why does "locate filename | xargs vim" cause strange terminal behaviour?

Tags: vim, terminal, xargs

When I do "locate 50local.policy | xargs vim", I get the error "Vim: Warnung: Die Eingabe kommt nicht von einem Terminal" (translation: Vim: Warning: The input does not come from a terminal).

I can edit successfully with vim but after I close it my terminal behaves strangely (I can't type letters and when I hit enter the shell prompt simply gets repeated.
When I do it with "xargs gedit" it does not create those problems.

I use Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome 3 and Gnome-Terminal 3.0.1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Vim expects to be connected to a real terminal and sends codes appropriate to that.

Reset the terminal with

```
reset
```

The easiest workaround:

```
locate 50local.policy | xargs gvim
```

> ***Rationale** gui vim doesn't require a terminal*

Otherwise:

```
vim $(locate 50local.policy)
```

> ***Rationale** vim is started directly connected to the terminal* (instead of as a child process under `xargs` which in turn runs in a subshell with stdin/stdout connected to pipes instead of a terminal). *It is like saying*
>
> ```
> vim /usr/some/dir/50local.policy /usr/local/some/dir/50local.policy
> ```

#### Alternatively

You can dodge the issue by not starting vim with the arguments, but adding the arguments from vim! Vim is in fact a lot better at running shells than shells are at running vim.

Whilst in vim:

```
:args `locate 50local.policy`
:rewind
```

This sets the argument list to the files returned from the shell command between the ticks; :rewind then goes to the first file from that list.
If you were editing multiple matches, try this:

```
:w|next
```

This sequence of commands (separated by |) writes the current buffer to file, then goes to the next file in the args list.

Comment: Just curious: what's the difference between `vim $(...)` and what the OP is doing?

Comment: @sidyll Added rationales in-post

Comment: @sidyll The OP is using `xargs` to create the `vim` process, while in the other case, the process is created from the shell.

Comment: Thanks sehe and @Philippe . Actually I never thought `xargs` would execute the command by itself…

Comment: @sidyll The point is that xargs executes it _with stdin/out not connected to a terminal_ (doing `echo hello | vim -` has the same issues).

Comment: @eMPee584 thanks for a helpful edit. I can't upvote it, but I would :)

Answer (score 6):

An other alternative is to execute `xargs` with the `-o` option. From the man page:

```
-o      Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing
        the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interac-
        tive application.
```

Note, `-o` is a BSD extension to xargs.

A more portable means to achieve the same effect is:

```
xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" < /dev/tty' vim
```

Answer (score 2):

While 'reset' fixes the problem, you can also explicitely re-activate the echo behaviour with:

```
stty echo
```