# using xargs vim with gnu screen

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, xargs

I've got a weird problem where if i do something like this in a gnu screen window, that window starts responding in weird ways

```
ls *.cpp | xargs vim
```

After I exit from vim, the screen window doesn't echo any command. It even does not echo CR.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you expecting VIM to open all the **cpp** file for you.
I would suggest you do this sort thing in **VIM** ,not in this way.

Comment: why don't use vim directly `vim *.cpp`

Comment: what would be wrong with `vim *.cpp` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does "locate filename | xargs vim" cause strange terminal behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228831/why-does-locate-filename-xargs-vim-cause-strange-terminal-behaviour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piping changes vim's stdin and causes problems. Try this instead (for bash, zsh, etc.):

```
vim $(find . -name "*.cpp")
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `vim *.cpp`?

Maybe `for file in *.cpp; do vim "$file"; done` could work too. Edit each file and exit.

Or start `vim` and add all `cpp` files with following command: `:argadd *.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

When using Vim in a pipe like this, you'll probably notice the following warning:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

That's Vim telling you that it cannot function as it's supposed to be (i.e. in interactive mode; you can still use it in "batch mode" by feeding it Ex commands to process). That explains the weirdness you experience after Vim quits.