# executing vi using the bash $ command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, vi

so I did this:

```
function wtfman(){
  local command="vi /the/path/file.txt"
  $($command)
}
```

with the desire for the program to open vi on that path

however, when I execute `wtfman` it instead returns

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

what did I do wrong and how do I go about reforming that function so that it opens vi accordingly instead of just complaining? ie I want a command stored in a string and I want to execute the command specified by that string. It works for everything else, but it's not working for vi (could it be because of vi's full screen nature?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does "locate filename | xargs vim" cause strange terminal behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228831/why-does-locate-filename-xargs-vim-cause-strange-terminal-behaviour)

Comment: What's wrong with `wtfman() { vi /the/path/file.txt; }`? There's no compelling reason to store the full command, with arguments, in a single variable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing in a subshell, use `eval` instead

```
function wtfman(){
  local command="vi /the/path/file.txt"
  eval "$command"
}
```

Or just...

```
function wtfman(){
  local command="vi /the/path/file.txt"
  $command
}
```

Or even just...

```
function wtfman(){
  vi /the/path/file.txt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$($command)`, just write `$command`.  This way, the command will inherit the stdout of the shell rather than having its stdout captured by the shell that invokes it.